# How to get the properties of the unique values in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Editing the question. From the pics how can i make an array within an object so that the data I get is as follows:

```
  { Access Panel: [Step 1, Step 2], 
   Air Extraction: [Step 1] }
```

On click the array is filterd, then outputs unique 'Subnames' based of input in text-box. How can I loop through the original array and i believe i need to create key/value pairs? Not sure what to do. Goal is populate 1 'Access Panel' button so that both Step 1 and Step 2 are populated on click.

removed pics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `Array.forEach()` function:

```js
const arr = [
   {subname: "Access Panel", stepnum: "Step 1"},
   {subname: "Access Panel", stepnum: "Step 2"},
   {subname: "Access Panel", stepnum: "Step 3"},
   {subname: "Air Extraction", stepnum: "Step 1"},
   {subname: "Air Extraction", stepnum: "Step 2"},
   {subname: "Random", stepnum: "Step 1"}
];

const obj = {};
arr.forEach((el) => { 
  if(!obj[el.subname]){
    obj[el.subname] = [el.stepnum];
  }else{
    obj[el.subname].push(el.stepnum);
  }
});

console.log(obj);
```

**Update:**

With `Array.reduce()`:

```js
const arr = [
   {subname: "Access Panel", stepnum: "Step 1"},
   {subname: "Access Panel", stepnum: "Step 2"},
   {subname: "Access Panel", stepnum: "Step 3"},
   {subname: "Air Extraction", stepnum: "Step 1"},
   {subname: "Air Extraction", stepnum: "Step 2"},
   {subname: "Random", stepnum: "Step 1"}
];

const res = arr.reduce((obj,el) => {
  obj[el.subname] = obj[el.subname] ? obj[el.subname].concat(el.stepnum) : [el.stepnum];
  return obj;
},{});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Could you also give me a brief explanation of what you're code is doing? Not sure what "  !obj  " purpose is?

Comment: Great stuff! thank you. how can i add more elements to the array within each subname? is it as easy as (el.stepnum, el.video, el.pdf etc.)